# How many people are in the room?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ratio

The ratio of men to women is $3:4$, the ratio of Americans to non-Americans is $7:2$, and the number of people that are in the room is less than $100$. How many people are in the room?

I am helping my younger brother out with math and, sadly, I don't remember how to do this. Could someone please give me a quick refreshing on this? 
P.S. I don't even know where to start - and I don't know exactly what this is called so I can't search it in order to find steps to solve this answer. 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hint: For the ration to be exactly 3:4, that means the total number of people must be divisible by a particular number.

Comment: **Hint:** The number of people in the room is both a multiple of $7$ (otherwise the gender ratio couldn't be exact) and a multiple of $9$ (otherwise the American fraction couldn't be exact).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Its a mere coincidence that the numbers 7 and 9 provided here have only one common multiple below 100....if it had more...it would be impossible...I was speaking of a generalised case....

Comment: More solutions would be possible if we accept the possibility of genderfluid people and/or dual citizens. :p

Comment: Do you remember how to find the LCM of a group of numbers ?

Comment: Well, conveniently, you've deleted your comment, so I can't point out how you were failing to address "the general case." You were quite speicific about what the number could be, and mentioned $1, 100, $ and $50$. @tatan

Comment: @trueblueanil, yes, I do.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Sorry if I had put forward something misleading....

Comment: Well do so, then !

Comment: @trueblueanil, Lol! Okay, Okay!

Comment: @HenningMakholm, thanks. Your answer was correct - It had to be the LCM of 7 & 9 - Thanks for your input, guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the number of men and american's in the room are both natural numbers, total number of people in the room must be divisible by both $(3+4)=7$ and $(7+2)=9$.

Now, $lcm(7,9)=63$.

We are told that the number of people in the room is less than 100. Hence, number of people in the room is exactly $63$. As the next number, after $63$, which is divisible by $7$ and $9$ both is $63\times 2=126>100$.

Comment: So, in future problems such as this - would you have to add the rations? I.e. $3:4 = 3 + 4$, etc? And then use the added rations to find the LCM? I.e $3+4 = 7$;  $7$, $x$ LCM.

Comment: I think you haven't understand the process properly. It's not mechanical. For example assume that your friend told you that he has some fruits. 1/3 of them are mangoes and 2/3 are apples. What you can tell immediately  from this? You can say that, total number of fruits he have is divisible by 3. Here the same thing has been used. Note that , your friend could have said the same thing by saying that he has some mangoes and apples and the ratio between mangoes and apples is 1:2. Hope you understand now. :-)

Comment: Maybe I didn't ask my question properly - why did you add the ratios together? i.e $ 3 + 4$

Comment: Let $N$ be the total number of people in the room. As, men to women ratio is $3:4\Rightarrow$ Number of men in the room is $N\times\frac{3}{3+4}=N\times\frac{3}{7}$ and similarly number of women in the room is $N\times\frac{4}{7}$. Observe that, if $N$ is not divisible by $7$ then number of men and no of women in the room would be fractions, which is not possible.